# C++ Websocket not receiving messages (websocketpp)

Tags: c++, websocket

I'm trying to get a minimal working websocket client in C++ using websocketpp (header-only library). I've gotten the program to compile and I have sorted through TLS handshake errors so that it now connects successfully, but I'm not receiving any messages. The output of the program is just:

```
Connecting to wss://echo.websocket.org
[2024-01-11 00:40:52] [connect] Successful connection
[2024-01-11 00:40:52] [connect] WebSocket Connection 66.241.124.119:443 v-2 "WebSocket++/0.8.2" / 101
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp>

typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client> client;
// typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;
typedef websocketpp::lib::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> context_ptr;

class websocket_endpoint {
public:
    websocket_endpoint () {
        m_endpoint.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        m_endpoint.clear_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::all);

        m_endpoint.init_asio();

        // For verbose logging
        m_endpoint.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        m_endpoint.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::connect);
        m_endpoint.set_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::all);

        m_endpoint.set_tls_init_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(&websocket_endpoint::on_tls_init, this, _1));

        m_endpoint.start_perpetual();

        m_thread.reset(new websocketpp::lib::thread(&client::run, &m_endpoint));
    }

    ~websocket_endpoint() {
        m_endpoint.stop_perpetual();

        if (m_thread) {
            m_thread->join();
        }
    }

    void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
        std::cout << "in on_open\n";
        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;

        // Send a test message
        m_endpoint.send(hdl, "Test message", websocketpp::frame::opcode::text, ec);
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Send failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Sent message: Test message" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void on_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
        std::cout << "in on_close\n";
    }

    void on_fail(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
        std::cout << "in on_fail\n";
    }

    // TLS Initialization Handler
    context_ptr on_tls_init(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
        context_ptr ctx(new boost::asio::ssl::context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12));

        ctx->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
        ctx->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none); // Disable certificate verification

        return ctx;
    }

    void on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl, client::message_ptr msg) {
        std::cout << "in on_message!\n";
        std::cout << msg->get_payload() << std::endl;
        if (msg->get_opcode() == websocketpp::frame::opcode::text) {
            std::string payload = msg->get_payload();
            // Now 'payload' contains your JSON string
            std::cout << "Received message: " << payload << std::endl;

            // If you want to parse this JSON, you can use a JSON library like nlohmann/json
        } else {
            std::cout << "error\n";
        }
    }

    void connect(std::string const & uri) {
        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;

        client::connection_ptr con = m_endpoint.get_connection(uri, ec);

        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Could not create connection because: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        m_endpoint.set_message_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(
            &websocket_endpoint::on_message,
            this,
            _1,
            _2
        ));

        // Set the on_open handler
        m_endpoint.set_open_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(
            &websocket_endpoint::on_open,
            this,
            _1
        ));

        m_endpoint.set_close_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(
            &websocket_endpoint::on_close,
            this,
            _1
        ));

        m_endpoint.set_fail_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(
            &websocket_endpoint::on_fail,
            this,
            _1
        ));

        m_endpoint.connect(con);
    }

private:
    client m_endpoint;
    websocketpp::lib::shared_ptr<websocketpp::lib::thread> m_thread;

};

int main() {
    websocket_endpoint endpoint;

    std::string uri = "wss://echo.websocket.org";
    std::cout << "Connecting to " << uri << std::endl;

    endpoint.connect(uri);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I'm on an M2 Macbook, and I'm running this to compile the program:
`g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.83.0/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.83.0/lib -lboost_system -lboost_thread-mt -DBOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS -lboost_chrono -lboost_random -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0_1/lib -lssl -lcrypto -I. test.cpp`

I confirmed that this websocket url works in Python and sends data:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def listen_to_websocket(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            print(message)

asyncio.run(listen_to_websocket('wss://echo.websocket.org'))
```

This prints out Request served by 1781505b56ee58.

Please let me know if there is a simpler way to do this - the whole thing has been more complicated than I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about `websocketpp` but I think you are missing a call to a `websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client>::run()` function. You need to call that after calling `websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client>::connect(uri)`.

A few other things might also be the issue. Debugging an asynchronous network operation can be challenging because you need to pinpoint the exact state of the system in the event-loop. Here are a few suggestions

1. **Lifetime Management:** Check to see if any of your stack variables are being destroyed prematurely. I'd suggest using more `print` statements in your constructor and destructor.
2. **Flushing the buffer**: Use `std::endl` instead of `\n`
3. **Simplify** this example and try it without SSL encryption if the server would allow it. At the very least it should return a `403` error code.